#  Finding "empty" portions in a file

Tags: c#, file

**EDIT 1:**

I build a torrent application; Downloading from diffrent clients simultaneously. Each download represent a portion for my file and diffrent clients have diffrent portions.
After a download is complete, I need to know which portion I need to achieve now by **Finding "empty" portions in my file**.

**One way to creat a file with fixed size:**

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\upload\BigFile.rar", new byte[Big  Size]);
```

**My portion Arr that represent my file as portions:**

```
BitArray TorrentPartsState = new BitArray(10);
```

**For example:**

File size is 100.

```
  TorrentPartsState[0] = true; // thats mean that in my file, from position 0 until 9 I **dont** need to fill in some information.
  TorrentPartsState[1] = true; // thats mean that in my file, from position 10 until 19 I **need** to fill in some information.
```

I seatch an effective way to save what the BitArray is containing even if the computer/application is shut down. One way I tought of, is by xml file and to update it each time a portion is complete.

I don't think its smart and effective solution. Any idea for other one?

Comment: Why would you do that? Maybe there is an easier way to achieve the goal. What data do you write to a file, is it text or binary or something else? Please post some code where you create a file of a fixed size.

Comment: You should provide more detail. What do you mean by empty? What's the xml for? Really confusing question.

Comment: Are there any patterns that could _never_ occur in valid data, e.g. 0xDEADBEEF?

Comment: @user92546 it is good qastion and thats what Im trying to find out.I tought of filling as -1 but I cant. By the way what is 0xDEADBEEF ?

Comment: 0xDEADBEEF was one of many easily recognizable patterns that were used in the ancient days of hex debuggers and memory dumps.  Unused memory was filled with it as were guard bands around allocated blocks of memory.  Now that it is easy to cast a reliable hex it is no longer used.

Comment: "Now that it is easy to cast a reliable hex it is no longer used" I did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you know the following when you start a transfer:

1. The size of the final file.
2. The (maximum) number of streams you intend to use for the file.

Create the output file and allocate the required space.

Create a second "control" file with a related filename, e.g. add you own extension.  In that file maintain an array of stream status structures corresponding to the network streams.  Each status consists of the starting offset and number of bytes transferred.  Periodically flush the stream buffers and then update the control file to reflect the progress made and *committed*.

Variations on the theme:

- The control file can define segments to be transferred, e.g. 16MB chunks, and treated as a work queue by threads that look for an incomplete segment and a suitable server from which to retrieve it.
- The control file could be a separate fork within the result file.  (Who am I kidding?)

Comment: there is no maximum stream but your idea is very good. im going for it and I will update in case it works ;) thanks you agian.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) (in System.Collections).

Then, when you visit on offset in the file, you can set the BitArray at that offset to true.

So for your 10,000 byte file:

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray(10000);

// Visited offset, mark in the BitArray            
ba[4] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a file system (like on a disk) in your file - just use something simple, should be something available in the FOS arena

Comment: Awesome.  Probably should implement journaling too.

Comment: No, that would be overkill (btw, you are aware that there are some PHENOMENALLY simple FS's right/)

Comment: what is FOS arena? Please explain more for your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Im sory but I did not understand your solution. Can you edit your anser and explain with more details? im sory agian.